# Is there a way to remove extra newlines from text using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I just wrote some code to strip extra newlines from some text.  Every set of contiguous newlines gets collapsed into a single newline.

This seems like it might be a good place to use LINQ to simplify the code.  Although I'm pretty new to LINQ and so not sure how to do this.  Can anyone suggest a solution?

Here is my original code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Collapse extra newlines.
/// </summary>
private string CollapseNewlines(string script)
{
    // Remove extra newlines.
    var lines = script.Split('\n');

    var output = new StringBuilder();

    bool prevLineWasEmpty = false;

    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        if (line.Trim() == string.Empty)
        {
            if (prevLineWasEmpty)
            {
                continue; // Ignore this line.
            }

            prevLineWasEmpty = true;
        }
        else
        {
            prevLineWasEmpty = false;
        }

        output.Append(line);
        output.Append("\n");
    }

    return output.ToString();
}
```

Comment: There's a Split overload to remove empty entries: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448.aspx - although it won't remove lines with only whitespace, as your code does.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this:

```
var lines = script.Split('\n')
            .Where(line => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line));

string output = string.Join("\n", lines);
```

Answer (score 5):

Why not rather use Regular Expressions?

Something like

```
Regex.Replace(source, @"(\r\n)+", "\r\n");
```

or

```
Regex.Replace(source, @"\n+", "\n");
```

[Regex Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx)

[Regex.Replace Method (String, String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1.aspx)